# Which following sets are not subspaces of R^3

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can someone explain to me why the following set is not subspace of $R^3$?

W = {($x^2$, y, x) ;  x and y are real numbers}

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For example:

$$(1,0,1)+(4,0,2)=(5,0,3)\notin W$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, $x^2$ is screaming "I'm not linear!", so we can expect that something will go wrong in the first component. Take $(1,1,1)\in W$, for example. Then $2(1,1,1) =(2,2,2)\not\in W$.